# After installing DD-WRT on Trendnet tew-828dru , I can't access router at all

Tags: dd-wrt

I installed DD-WRT through the web interface of my tew-828dru. After it reboots, it no longer broadcasts the SSID, I can't connect by manually entering the SSID, and I can't connect through ethernet. If I plug the ethernet cable in, I get some obscure IP address and I can't ping the router at all, nor am I able to SSH to it. If I do a full 30/30/30 on it to restore the firmware to the factory default, then I can access it again. I've never had this problem with DD-WRT before, and Trendnet openly supports it for this particular router, so I'm very confused as to what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to connect to it through an SSH connection?  *I get some obscure IP address* - Can you be more specific.  If "manually" means you can't establish an SSH connection you should state that.

Comment: Updated with some additional info. But no, I am not able to SSH to the router. I can't even ping it. I get a random 169.1.something IP address if I connect through ethernet, but then can't do anything from there.

Comment: Can you give me the entire address?  There is no possible leakage, because its not possible for 169.1.x.x, to be a public addressable ip address.  You need to update your question with this information.

Comment: I'll update it when I get home tonight. I wasn't concerned about leakage, just couldn't remember the full address off the top of my head :)

Comment: Any event, I can tell you that the ip address your being assigned, means DHCP isn't working.  169.254.0.0/16 addresses are allocated for communication between hosts and a single link.   [RFC3927](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735) indicates that hosts, obtain these addresses by auto-configuration, such as when a DHCP server cannot be found.  *I am going to guess your router is bricked.*  I am almost certain your being assigned in the 169.254.0.0/16 subnet instead of the 169.1.0.0/24 subnet

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I'll attach the full IP when I get home. I've repeated the process several times, and the results are always exactly the same. If I perform the 30/30/30 it restores the original firmware and it's fine. As soon as I install DD-WRT, boom. I'm using the firmware from Trednet's own website for this exact model router that's verified to work, and am following their process for flashing it (via the web interface), which is why I find this so strange.

Comment: [This is a known problem with the DD-WRT TrendNET distrubuted](https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=284667&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0), but that might a different problem, point is the build TrendNET has on their website is old and likely the problem.

Comment: What version of the product do you have?

Comment: You need to build the current branch of DD-WRT against the Broadcom`BCM43602`either that find the [current build for your router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation#Upgrading_to_a_Newer_Version_of_DD-WRT) I suggest you just build it yourself.

Comment: The IP I get is 169.254.253.44. I'm using the latest version from here: ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/betas/2017/05-02-2017-r31924/trendnet-828DRU/ - that version should be built for my specific router from what I gather?

Comment: So your using that version?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I'm using right now. I also tried the version directly from Trendnet's website, as well as a couple older versions from dd-wrt.com. All of them have the same result though.

Comment: Honestly is sounds like it's the fault of the hardware

Comment: It's starting to seem that way. Maybe I just need to RMA it, since one of the big things they advertise with this router is DD-WRT compatibility.